# Constantly running into missing packages on webapp

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, nuget

I've built a webapp I'm trying to deploy it to IIS.

It works just fine on my local computer, but when I try to browse it after importing it to IIS on a remote server as an application, it's nearly impossible to get past the homepage. Every other page throws up some kind of server error, stating that it's missing some reference. I add that reference, and it throws up another missing reference.

The problem is starting to get ridiculous. It's now complaining that it can't find Mono.Security 2.0.0.0. If I look at the [NuGet gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Security/) for this package, there are only two versions, both of them much newer than 2.0. Am I really expected to continue installing out of date packages? I have Mono.Security 5.4.0 installed - why isn't it using that instead? I feel like it's dangerous to continue installing these ancient packages, and I have no clue why it's asking for them in the first place. Can anyone help clear this up?

At the very least, could someone explain why it's looking for these packages in the first place? I started this project like two weeks ago - why is it still referencing packages that are probably a decade old by now and severely deprecated?

Additionally, is there some easy way to tell the program to remove all aggressively old, outdated packages and use something recent instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use web.config to add assembly redirection. That's the common practice which should not be a surprise to most .NET developers. To track where such old reference comes from, you just need a tool like ILSpy.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but in a one-off manner. I guess I was hoping there was a way to scan all of the assemblies, look for updates, and auto-redirect them (or something along those lines). It's just kind of a lot of hand-jamming that I'd assumed had been automated at some point. No biggie though, thanks for the suggestion either way.